# How do we fade in to a opacity for a component in Sencha Touch?

Tags: animation, sencha-touch

I am trying to fade out a toolbar and use the Ext.Anim class to run a fade in/out transition based on the click of a button. However, I would like to make the toolbar as an overlay with a transparency on top of the existing panel.

When I do the animation, the opacity however gets restored back to 1 (default opacity for fade animation) instead of the value I had defined for the toolbar. How do I set a toOpacity for the fade anim?

Fade-in/out code as below:

```
                show: function() {
                Ext.Anim.run(this, 'fade', {
                    out: false,
                    to:{
                        opacity:0.6
                    },
                    from:{
                        opacity:0
                    },
                    autoClear: false
                });
            },
            hide: function() {
                Ext.Anim.run(this, 'fade', {
                    out: true,
                    to:{
                        opacity:0
                    },
                    from:{
                        opacity:0.6
                    },
                    autoClear: false
                });
            }
```